# How do I pass an opened filehandle as the parameter of a function?

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a main script that calls a function from another module. I open a file in the main script, and I want to use the filehandle attached to this file as a parameter in the function called (I don't want to open the file in the function because I will be calling the same function on the same file several times, so opening it every time wouldn't make sense).

In my main script:

```
open(my $IN_FILE, "<input.txt") or die "Can't open: $!\n";
open(my $OUT_FILE, ">output.txt") or die "Can't open: $!\n";

AnotherModule->ProcessDBU($IN_FILE, $OUT_FILE);
```

In `AnotherModule`:

```
sub ProcessDBU{
    my $IN_FILE = $_[0];
    my $OUT_FILE = $_[1];

    local $/ = ' ';

    while(<$IN_FILE>){
        SomeProcess();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run the script, this error occurs:

```
readline() on unopened filehandle at AnotherModule.pm line 7.
```

What's preventing me from using the filehandle? Why is it unopened? What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling a function as a method.

```
AnotherModule->ProcessDBU($IN_FILE, $OUT_FILE);
```

should be

```
AnotherModule::ProcessDBU($IN_FILE, $OUT_FILE);
```

Three differences:

- Method calls search the inheritance hierarchy,
- method calls ignore prototypes, and
- method calls pass the invocant (what's left of `->`) as the first argument.

Comment: Ahhh, that was an easy fix. I didn't even know there was a difference between the two.

Comment: method calls pass the object or class the method is being called on as the first parameter.  so your $IN_FILE in the sub was actually "AnotherModule".